# Cannot reinstall SQL Server 2008 R2 after downgrade from Windows 10 to Windows 7

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, installation

**Scenario**: using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express under Windows 7 without problems.

Then I upgraded to Windows 10 without problems.

Then I downgraded back to Windows 7 (due to problems with other applications). SQL Server is gone.

When I run `x64_ENU + SQLEXPR_x64_ENU` to reinstall I get the following error message during "Setup Support Files" (with `ExecuteStandardTimingsWorkflow` apparently the current task) and cannot go further:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup The following error has occurred: An
>   error occurred during the installation of assembly
>   'policy.8.0.Microsoft.VC80.CRT,version="8.0.50727.42",type="win32-policy",
>   processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"'.

Running `SFC  /SCANNOW` did not reveal any problems.

`Program_Install_And_Uninstall` also did not. Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package (x64) was not installed, so I installed it.

Now SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup ran a lot further, but then generated a similar (but not identical) error at

> Install_SqlSupport_KatmaiRTM_Cpu64_Action: CreateShortcuts

The following components were installed:

- SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client
- SQL Server 2008 R2 Policies
- SQL Server 2008 R2 setup (English)
- SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU
- SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 Query Tools ENU

Deleting all these, and also all components of Visual Studio, and trying again did not change this.

Comment: Re-installation of .NET Framework didn't help unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

A few more suggestions—adding as an answer to accept more characters so I can include more. . .

**BE SURE TO RUN EVERYTHING AS ADMINISTRATOR**

- Command prompt (as administrator) run `SFC /SCANNOW` - Once this completed, check the log file it points to in the window for other errors and post back that as an edit to your question, I think it's called CBS.log, so just look for error with the date and time around the time you run once it's complete
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/mats/program_install_and_uninstall
- You may want to ensure this is installed (or uninstall re-install)
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21254
- If you have Visual Studio installed, you may want to consider uninstalling and reinstalling it as well
- If there are any other prerequisite components installed on this system for SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, you may want to consider uninstalling and reinstalling those as well - see notes below

Note, sometimes with the SQL Server and Visual Studio and other components, software, etc. as such, you have to install them in the order based on their version or things in the Windows registry, DLL component, etc. just get out of wack.

For example, if you have some component (or software) of the 2005 and 2008 version you need, it's best to install the oldest first (2005) and then once that is complete install the newest (2008).  I've seen this too many times where someone installs some old component or software as such on top of newer software, etc. that's already installed then the system start having strange problems.

If all else fails, you can backup your important data, and then do a fresh wipe of your HD and install a fresh copy of Windows. Microsoft has no way of emulating all software on everyone computers in the whole world, so perhaps when you upgraded and then downgraded, something just got corrupt and there was something on your system that they didn't test with, etc.  I typically always do fresh system upgrades rather than in-place upgrades but I'm in a business environment mainly too.

Comment: Thank you, but see extended question

Comment: PJMahoney Tried a new download, but got the same result. As I also have problems with various other applications and drivers, I am fast coming to the conclusion that a trip back to the shop for a (OEM) reinstall of Windows 7 is the best (only) option. Many thanks for your efforts on my behalf..

Comment: No problem, I tried what I could.  Remotely and in-person are two different things.

Comment: Reinstalled Windows 7 and then SQL Server. It worked (of course). Lesson: try not to have to downgrade from Windows 10 to Windows 7